# How to talk about a dilemma in the past tense?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I have this sentence fragment -

> prompting my morally dilemm**ed** conscience to become...

Obviously this doesn't sound grammatically correct and I can't find any information about it online. Can anyone help me with a suggestion?

Comment: I have never seen the word "dilemmed" – are you hoping to make an adjective from 'dilemma'? A conscience does not have two states. It is the brain which has a dilemma so I suggest [**stricken**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stricken).

Comment: Can you expand on this? "Prompting my morally [dilemma] conscience.." also wouldn't work in present tense. Do you want to convey the idea that your conscience had a dilemma (or that you had a conscientious dilemma) but no longer? Why not simply say that your 'conscience had a moral dilemma'?

Comment: The etymology might help. _Dilemma_ means 'two proofs', meaning two conflicting analyses, which is why one is on the 'horns' of a dilemma. You could use _trilemma_ if you just needed to add another contradiction, or  you could resort to the verb _lemmatize_ in its various regular forms, like _lemmatization_.

Comment: If you were inventing a word, I'd make it "dilemmaed" although the spelling "dileamma'd" might be preferred by some people. Dropping the final "a" is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to have a transitive verb from *dilemma* but dictionary search produces none. You might consider the more conventional *divided conscience*

Here is one example of many to be found online. This one uses the phrase in the title and implies its involvement with dilemmas within the following text.

> *Dostoevskii and the Divided Conscience*
>
> In the decade between the Russian revolutions of 1905 and 1917, many of the Russian radical intelligentsia believed that Dostoevskii had anticipated their moral dilemmas…
>
> [Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/slavic-review/article/abs/dostoevskii-and-the-divided-conscience/4AEBB66560B253E9EE7ACDEE43F8E0D5)